# Is a finite extension over a normal domain also normal?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

If $A$ is a normal domain, $B$ is a module-finite $A$-algebra, and $B$ is also a domain is $B$ necessarily normal? If it is, how to prove it; if not, is there any counterexample?

If not, what if $A$ is a UFD, or even stronger, a polynomial ring with $n$ indeterminates over a field?

Comment: If this is homework, you should say so...

Comment: Do you know any examples from algebraic number theory?

Comment: This is something that I would like to generalize from my homework but could not figure out how to do.

Comment: If this is true for any $B$ as in your statement, then $A$ must be a field.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. For instance, $\mathbf Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is finite over $\mathbf Z$, but not normal.

It isn't true either over a polynomial ring. Hint: think of a non-smooth affine curve mapping down to $\mathbf A^1$.

Comment: Can you elaborate a litte bit more on the non-smooth affine curve case? thank you very much.

Comment: @Alex Do you know an example of a non-smooth curve?

Comment: Sorry, I am not very familier with algebraic geometry, so I don't know whether you mean affine variety or anything else?